# Вывести слово в рамку из звездочек Python

Tags: python

Не могу понять в чём у меня ошибка. Задание следующее:

Создайте программу, которая запрашивает у пользователя слово и выводит слово в звездочках со словом посередине. Ширина рамок составляет 30 знаков, и вы можете предположить, что слово поместится в рамки.

Примечание! Если слово нечетной длины, вы можете напечатать слово в любом из возможных центров.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код :

```
 a = input("word: ")
    b=30
    print("*" * b)
    if len(a) <= b:
        print("*", " " * (b//2 -len(a)) + a," " * (b//2 - len(a)), "*") 
    print("*" * b)
```

Выводит как то неправильно...Спасибо...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = input('Word: ')
w = int(input('Width: '))  

print('*' * w + '\n' + '*' + s.center(w-2) + '*' + '\n' + '*' * w)
# либо
print(f"{'*'*w}\n*{s.center(w-2)}*\n{'*'*w}")
```

Comment: Спасибо !!!   Помогли!!!

Comment: пожалуйста......

Answer (score 2):

Можно в одну строку вывести через join и format

```
s = 'example'
w = 30

print('\n'.join(['*' * w, '*{:^{wid}}*'.format(s, wid=w-2), '*' * w]))
```